# Connect to vmware virtual machine via network

Tags: vmware-workstation, virtualization

I want to connect to my vmware vm from home.

To work network i'm connecting through VPN.

VM sits on one of the workstations (can connect to it through RDC).

Any tips how to do that? What software do i need (got VMWare workstation atm)?

p.s. i'm quite a newbie at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you can RDP to this VM from a separate machine within your work LAN then you should be able to do the same from your home system if you are allowed to open a VPN connection to your work network. It's possible that your work network might block RDP over the VPN link, again test this by connecting to a machine that you know RDP works for when connecting from within your work LAN.

The basic set up on your VMware Workstation system will require that you use bridged networking to connect your VM to your work network (not NAT or local only).

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you have set the VM's networking. If it is "host" only or NAT), you can't do it (at least not directly). But if you set it as bridged, then the VM will have it's own IP address on the network, and once connected to the VPN, you should be able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can also do this in NAT mode with PORT FORWARDING!

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210119063317/http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2009/11/13/connect-to-vmware-virtual-machines-using-remote-desktop.aspx)

Comment: I think you've got the wrong understanding of the question.